# How to call formdata parameters in Java POST

Tags: java, ajax, multipartform-data

I am passing formData in Ajax, how can I process in Java POST?

```
    formData.append(file.name, file);
    formData.append('para', 'true');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'example.com/test',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
    })
```

and in Java,

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("test")
public getJSONFromMultipart(@Multipart(value = "para") boolean test, @Multipart(value = "uploadedFile") Attachment att, @Context final UriInfo info) { ... }
```

I am getting a compile error for MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, and so multipart errors. Is that the right way to call formData?

Answer (score 0):

Which package are you using for `MediaType` ? `MediaType` exists in Java EE jar but also in Spring Web jar.

These are not of the same type.

In Spring class : `org.springframework.http.MediaType`

```
public class MediaType{
    ...
    public final static MediaType MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
}
```

In Java EE class : `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`

```
public class MediaType{
    ...
    public final static String MULTIPART_FORM_DATA= "multipart/form-data";
}
```

and why not using constant both in `@Produces` and `@Consumes` ?

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
```

As you declare your handler in Java EE way, you should be careful when you choose your imports.